# Why does Python string fail to compare correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, string-comparison

I am comparing two strings in Python. But the comparison fails to see that the values of variables `firmware` and `hardware` are the same as the strings `"firmware"` and `"hardware`".

```
gfirmware = create_string_buffer(str.encode("firmware"), 100)
ghardware = create_string_buffer(str.encode("hardware"), 100)
firmware = str(gfirmware,'utf-8')
hardware = str(ghardware,'utf-8')

print('firmware var = ' + firmware)
print('hardware var = ' + hardware)
print("\n")
print('firmware type = ' + str(type(firmware)))
print('hardware type = ' + str(type(hardware)))
print('"firmware" type = ' + str(type("firmware")))
print('"hardware" type = ' + str(type("hardware")))

print("Is it true? " + str(firmware != "firmware" and hardware != "hardware"))
```

**Output:**

```
firmware var = firmware
hardware var = hardware

firmware type = <class 'str'>
hardware type = <class 'str'>
"firmware" type = <class 'str'>
"hardware" type = <class 'str'>
Is it true? True
```

The values and the types of the variables and the strings are the same, as can be seen in the output.

So why does the comparison `firmware != "firmware" and hardware != "hardware"` return `True`, it should be returning `False`?

**Note:**
I am intentionally using `create_string_buffer()` because I am passing `gfirmware` and `ghardware` into a C function. But this issue occurs even though I am not passing the variables into a C function.

I have looked at the following and other posts, but their issues were that the programmer was using the keyword `is` when they should have been using `==`.

[Why does comparing strings using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce-a-differe)

[python fails to compare strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479955/python-fails-to-compare-strings)

[Strange behavior when comparing unicode objects with string objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20438652/strange-behavior-when-comparing-unicode-objects-with-string-objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `gfirmware` and `ghardware` objects are large character buffers. When you convert them to strings with `str(gfirmware,'utf-8')` you get large strings:

```
>>> len(str(gfirmware, 'utf-8'))
100
```

because you still have all the padding.

You can use the `value` property on the buffers before converting to a string:

```
>> firmware = str(gfirmware.value,'utf-8')
>> hardware = str(ghardware.value,'utf-8')
>> firmware != "firmware", hardware != "hardware"
(False, False)
```

Comment: It didn't occur to me that it would be comparing padding as well. The C programmer in me thinks `0` as string termination character.

Comment: ah.. and I thought that this fn was just some user defined code w/o any connection to the problem altough it crossed my mind for a second... now I see this is python lib/ foreign func

Comment: Yeah @Fred — it doesn't help that `print(str(gfirmware,'utf-8'))`  shows you what looks like a nice normal string. `print(repr(str(gfirmware,'utf-8')))` will show you the `repr` versions in all its padded glory.

Comment: This is why it's important to debug properly before asking.